# Copy text in Textview inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a ScrollView with some textview inside. But when I'm trying to copy it, nothing happens, because scrollview intercepts all movements. How to fix this? The same behaviour in map, I can't scroll it vertically

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contact_appBarLayout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/contacts_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contacts_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contacts_map"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_24dp">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/contacts_address_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_dark_636363"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_14sp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/contacts_address_subtitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: how you are highlighting text?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Highlight here ? Are you using Span or `scrollTo()` or anything else . Post your Code ,

Comment: look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480785/8516127)

Comment: @MiteshMachhoya I mean that I can't copy text

Comment: @PinkRabbits it's not working